# Why does Yuri hate Kanata?

Tags: sky-wizards-academy

Yuri hates Kanata for some reason because she calls him a traitor in the first episode.

Why is that and why does she hate him so much?

Comment: He had platoon and invited, trained her. Then left platoon and she got mad (typical tsundere).

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in episode 2 by Misora Whitale.

Yuri hates Kanata because in the match when their fireteam was supposed to get promoted, Kanata did not take part in that match. Yuri was so much was with that, and thus she hates Kanata.